# Book suggestions on Bi-homogeneous Forms of Bi-degree $(d,e)$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $$F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=x_1y_1y_2^2+x_2y_1^2y_2.$$
Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be real scalars. Since:
$$F(c_1\mathbf{x},c_2\mathbf{y})=c_1c_2^3F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}),$$ we call $F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ a **bihomogeneous form of bidegree (1,3)**. I am looking for a book that talks about this. Any suggestion?